# How to create a slice object that selects all elements?

Tags: python

I am building up `slice`s programatically for reasons, and would like to create a slice that grabs "everything".  My immediate intuition was that

```
my_slice = slice()
```

would produce an object such that

```
assert (my_list[my_slice] == my_list) #True
```

However, a quick look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) reveals that `slice` *requires* a `stop` parameter.

Can I obtain an object `all_slice` such that `any_list[all_slice] == any_list` for all `any_list`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `None`:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_slice = slice(None)
print(my_list[my_slice])
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```